# Flutter: Is there any way to start the Stopwatch class at a given time?

Tags: flutter

I was hoping for something like below but obviously this does not work.

```
  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.elapsed = watch.elapsed + Duration(hours: 01, minutes: 23, seconds: 31);
```

Is there any way of achieving the desired result ?

-Thanks for any hint/clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stopwatch` is for measuring intervals - normally used in performance testing. Perhaps you want a `Timer`. Or subclass stopwatch.

```
  Timer t = Timer(Duration(hours: 01, minutes: 23, seconds: 31), () {
    print('time to take the cake out of the oven');
  });
  ...
  t.cancel(); // use this if you want to cancel the timer early


class OffsetStopwatch extends Stopwatch {
  Duration offset;

  OffsetStopwatch(this.offset);

  Duration get offsetElapsed => offset + elapsed;
}
```

Comment: Can the Timer Class count up ? I assumed it could only count down ? Thanks for the help ?